# Removing a File Extention from a String in Python (Reverse Indexing)

Tags: python, string, find, substring

In a recent project I had to remove the '.txt' extention in a string. I tried using the `.find()` function as well as `.index()` and `.search()` in many ways but nothing came out of it. So, I wrote the following:

```
file_name = 'myFile.txt is a file'
new_name = file_name[:(len(file_name) - len(file_name.split('.')[len(file_name.split('.')) - 1]) - 1)]

print(new_name)
```

Output

```
myFile
```

It worked fine.

However I was wondering if there was something simpler and cleaner that I could do with reverse indexing... Something that could work not only with extentions but in other similar cases as well. For some reason I couldn't find something that works efficiently in other posts.
Any help would be highly appreciated : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use Regex to seach for the text preceeding the . character:

```
import re

file_name = 'myFile.txt is a file'

new_name = re.findall(r'(\w+)\.', file_name)[0]

print(new_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Main problem I see here is your file_name object is not really the file name, it's a statement saying the file name. In this case I would use a different approach. First, divide the words in the statement with

```
words = file_name.split(' ')
```

Then I would have a list of words. Then, one by one, I would try to find the filename

```
file = None 
for word in words:
    if '.' in word:
        file = word.split('.')
```

Now you have the filename.

```
file_name = file[0]
file_extension = file[1]
```

If you are sure that the filename provided is always going to be filename and extension, then you only need to split it by '.' and take the index of 0 and 1 to get the name and extension.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, when you say this

> Something that could work not only with extentions but in other similar cases as well

My implementation of what you presented would be the following.

```
new_name = file_name.split('.')[0]
# Or if multiple periods are possible and you care about the last one
new_name = '.'.join(file_name.split('.')[:-1])
```

But a more general solution would depend on what those "other similar cases" could be.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly... What I meant by that was whether there is a way for the program to separate it and recognise if it is an existing extention or not.